# Sorting technique - most efficient

Tags: sorting

What sorting technique would you use to sort 10,000 items using just 1000 available slots in your RAM?

1. Heap Sort
2. Quick Sort
3. Bubble Sort
4. Merge Sort

I am confused between quick and merge sort. Both have average time complexity of nlogn but again heap sort also has the same complexity. Any inputs would be appreciated!

Comment: You're talking about time complexity, but it sounds like the question is actually asking about space complexity.

Comment: Oh right I was thinking about time complexity but yes now I get it. Accessing the slots in constant time should be important here right? heap sort does that in constant time but still not sure enough.

Comment: The question doesn't specify where the 10,000 items are stored. Are they also in main memory or in external memory, such as a file? If the 10,000 items are stored in memory, then heap sort can sort them without using any additional memory for items, and possibly with all variables in registers. Quick sort would need some memory for a stack. A near in place merge sort that uses a 1000 element working buffer would also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time complexity won't help you here - what the question is looking for is space complexity. Just as a hint, `n = 10000` and you have only 1000 available spaces, so you need to pick an algorithm that is better than `O(n)` space complexity even in the worst case.

Comment: Yep, the key is to make sure that the space complexity isn't going to cause you to go over the 1000 extra spaces permitted even in the worst case.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an HW question, so I'd prefer not to answer directly. In general, though, since your RAM is small and your list is big, you'll do best with something like a [cache oblivious algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache-oblivious_algorithm).